# texto adicionado com append não respeita div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho uma lista que seus elementos são adicionados com o append do jquery e o texto adicionado não respeita limites da div e nem da lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

css:

```
#list_arquivos{
  list-style:none;
}

#list_arquivos .arquivo{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#list_arquivos .nome_arquivo{
  width: 70px;
}

#list_arquivos img{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="dropzone">
     <ul id="list_arquivos"></ul>
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#list_arquivos").append(
      '<li class="arquivo">'+
      '<a href="#">'+
      '<img src="img/file_icons/'+dados.icon+'">' +
      '<p class="nome_arquivo">'+dados.nome_arquivo+'</p>'+
      '</a>'+
      '</li>'
 );
```

Quero que o texto abaixo da imagem, independente do seu tamanho, não ultrapasse os 100px que delimitei para a tag p onde ele fica.

Comment: Quer q o texto quebre para baixo?

Comment: @ÐvÐ Sim, tentei de tudo ele não quebra de jeito nenhum. Se eu colocar direto no html o texto quebra mas quando adiciono com o append ele fica daquele jeito lá na imagem.

Comment: manda um print disso pra eu dar uma olhada

Comment: @ÐvÐ  https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/88d1fe08-8c28-4d79-b42e-aff5541dcd67.png

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70020/discussion-between-leandro-silva-campos-and-dvd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclua `word-wrap: break-word;` em `#list_arquivos .arquivo{` para que palavras longas sejam quebradas para caber dentro da `div`. [[Mais sobre o estilo]](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Em adicional, coloque no mesmo seletor o estilo `vertical-align: top;` para alinhar as `divs` no topo.

```css
#list_arquivos{
  list-style:none;
}

#list_arquivos .arquivo{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#list_arquivos .nome_arquivo{
  width: 70px;
}

#list_arquivos img{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone">
   <ul id="list_arquivos">
      <li class="arquivo">
         <a href="#">
            <img src="img/file_icons/">
            <p class="nome_arquivo">dvdvdvd d d dhhdsddsddssfddffdhd dh</p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="arquivo">
         <a href="#">
            <img src="img/file_icons/">
            <p class="nome_arquivo">fddffdhd dh</p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="arquivo">
         <a href="#">
            <img src="img/file_icons/">
            <p class="nome_arquivo">dvdvdvd d d dhhdsddsddssfddffdhd dh</p>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```